# Dictionary-based NLTK tagger

Tags: geolocation, nlp, nltk, tagging, stanford-nlp

I want to tag location string in text using NLTK and also in Stanford-NLP

and am looking for dictionary lookup tagger for NLTK/Stanford-NLP, for so far I haven't found anything with  Dictionary-lookup method.

One way is to use RegexpTagger(NLTK) and supply every location strings in there, but it might slow.

I don't need to do any semantic analysis, other than to tag the locations based on my location-dictionary.

Ideas ?

Comment: can you give an entry of how your location-dictionary looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `UnigramTagger`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from nltk.tag.sequential import UnigramTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize

text = 'I visited Paris and Bordeaux. Not Los Angeles'

locations = [[('Paris', 'LOC'), ('Bordeaux', 'LOC'), ('France', 'LOC'),
              ('Los Angeles', 'LOC')]]    
location_tagger = UnigramTagger(locations)

for sentence in sent_tokenize(text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
    print(location_tagger.tag(tokens))
```

Prints:

```py
[('I', None), ('visited', None), ('Paris', 'LOC'), ('and', None),
 ('Bordeaux', 'LOC'), (',', None), ('but', None), ('not', None),
 ('Los', None), ('Angeles', None)]
```

You will need a better tokenizer if you want to tag multi-word locations like Los Angeles.

Comment: thanks. the tricky part, as you said, was to tag bigram and trigram. what tokenizer do you suggest ?

Comment: If all you need is grouping 'Los' and 'Angeles' (say), the easiest way is to do it yourself after applying the unigram tagger, but it isn't really extensible to other improvements, eg. handling ambiguity or other types of tags.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to look up from dictionaries, then htql.RegEx() may be a good fit.  Here is the example from http://htql.net:

```
import htql; 
address = '88-21 64th st , Rego Park , New York 11374'
states=['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 
    'Delaware', 'District Of Columbia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 
    'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 
    'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 
    'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 
    'Oregon', 'PALAU', 'Pennsylvania', 'PUERTO RICO', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 
    'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 
    'Wyoming']; 

a=htql.RegEx(); 
a.setNameSet('states', states);

state_zip1=a.reSearchStr(address, "&[s:states][,\s]+\d{5}", case=False)[0]; 
# state_zip1 = 'New York 11374'

state_zip2=a.reSearchList(address.split(), r"&[ws:states]<,>?<\d{5}>", case=False)[0]; 
# state_zip2 = ['New', 'York', '11374']
```

You can use parameter: useindex=True to return matching positions.